# Trying to port Chrome Javascript Extension to Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari

I've been trying to port a very simple extension from Chrome to Safari but had no success so far.

I know that it's utterly unacceptable to ask someone to do this, but if any one with the knowledge about how Safari behaves could help adjusting (or tipping how to) this code I'd be really, really thankful.

The purpose of the code is to get the URL of a image and attach it to the latter part of the baseUrl opening it on a new tab, so it gets uploaded to our website.

I tried to read Apple Safari's documentation on how the code should be in order to open this new tab using the URL from the image, but the extension simply won't work.

```
    function uploadToMyPix(ctx) {
        var baseUrl="http://xxxx.com/api?&key=xxxx&format=redirect&upload="+ctx.srcUrl;
        uploadImage(baseUrl);
    }



    function uploadImage(imgUrl) {
        var behaviour = window.localStorage.behaviour;
            if (behaviour == "new_unfocused") {
                chrome.tabs.create({
                url: url,
                selected: false
                });
            } else if (behaviour == "new") {
                chrome.tabs.create({
                url: imgUrl,
                selected: true
                });
            } else if (behaviour == "new_window") {
                chrome.windows.create({
                url: imgUrl,
                });
            } else {
                chrome.tabs.create({
                url: imgUrl,
                });
            }
    }

    chrome.contextMenus.create({title: chrome.i18n.getMessage("ctxMenuStringMyPix"), contexts:["image"], onclick: uploadToMyPix});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know safari extensions but [this series](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-extendsafari/index.html) may be of help to you. It shows you how to build the same extension in chrome, firefox, and safari.